# How would you find the geodesic distance travelled by a photon in a matter dominated universe?

Tags: cosmology, photons, geodesics

Suppose a photon in an Einstein-de sitter universe (matter-dominated) is emitted at redshift $z = z_1$ and received at $z = 0$, how would I find the geodesic distance between them?

I understand that the scale factor $a(t)$ evolves with time $t$, such that $a(t) = \big(\frac{3}{2}H_0t\big)^\frac{2}{3}$, and that the length of curves in space (between A and B) is given as $L = \int_{A}^B ds$. I don't know what to do with these, and how you can perform a change of variables such that you integrate from $z_1$ to $z_2$?

Answer (score 1):

The geodesic distance is going to be zero. If you want to calculate something nontrivial, it would have to be the distance perpendicular to the Hubble flow at some time t in Friedmann coordinates, maybe the final time. Write down the expression for the line element, $ds^2=\ldots$, set it equal to zero, separate variables, and integrate.